# add/removeClass for array display - sonarqube

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, sonarqube

i am analyzing my code using sonarqube and coming across an error in the following function:

```
$(function () {
     $("#SSNCollection input[type=text]").keydown(function (evt) {

         var IsNullEmptyText = "true";
         var ssntxtArrayText = [];
         var txtLength = 0;
         $("#SSNCollection input[type=text]").each(function () {
             var _tempValues = $(this).val().toString().replace(/[-]/g, '').trim();
             if (!isNaN(this.value.toString().replace(/[-]/g, '').trim())) {
                        var _temptxtlength = this.value.toString().replace(/[-]/g, '').trim().length;

                        ssntxtArrayText.push(_tempValues);
                    }
                });
                $.each(ssntxtArrayText, function (index, value) {
                    if (value.length >= 0) {
                        $('#resultValidation').css({
                            'display': 'none',
                        });
                        return false;
                    } else {
                        $("#resultValidation").removeAttr("style");
                    }

                });
            });
        });
```

the issue starts with the `if (value.length >= 0) {`. because an array length will always be >=0 the `if` and the following `else` are unnecessary.
thus i changed the statement to

```
$.each(ssntxtArrayText, function (index, value) {
       $('#resultValidation').css({
              'display': 'none',
       });
       return false;
});
```

my issue now is that i'm being told that i should use `addClass('hidden')` and `removeClass('hidden')`as i may need the else statement after all. but i'm not sure how i'd utilize those in this case. any ideas? thanks!

Comment: use `toggleClass('hidden')` - http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/ this will add or remove the class `hidden` from the element(s)

Comment: all that in the `$.each(ssntxtArrayText, function (index, value) {let t = (value.length >= 0);
$('#resultValidation').toggleClass('hidden',t);
return !t;});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ***hidden*** class is typically included in CSS frameworks such as Bootstrap. If you are not using Bootstrap (*or you aren't sure*), simply add the following CSS to your project css file.

```
.hidden { display:none!important; }
```

or inline html version

```
<style>.hidden { display:none!important; }</style>
```

On the note of using conditional logic - after reviewing your code, I can confirm that the **value** variable does not return an array. It does in fact return a string value which means that checking if the length is greater than or equal to 0 is appropriate. If you want to check the array length before running the `$.each`, simply wrap the `$.each` in an `if(ssntxtArrayText.length > 0)` statement. The following example shows proper implementation of using **.addClass()** & **.removeClass()** and checking if the array has any values before running.

```
if(ssntxtArrayText.length > 0) {
    $.each(ssntxtArrayText, function (index, value) {
        if (value.length >= 0) {
            $('#resultValidation').addClass('hidden'); //hide
            return false;
        } else {
            $("#resultValidation").removeClass('hidden'); //unhide
        }
    });
}
```

Note: If you are checking for valid social security numbers, I recommend ensuring that the value has a length of 9 characters. This would be done like so: `if (value.length == 9) {`